How do I add an image to the title page in the [oneside]{book} document class? More specifically, how would I add them side-by side?
The current preamble is as follows (ignore the usage of author and date for the supervisors):
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\graphicspath{{./Images/}}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb}


\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\parskip=\baselineskip
\parindent=0pt

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
 
   linkcolor=black,
 
   filecolor=magenta,      

   urlcolor=cyan,

    pdftitle={Project},

pdfpagemode=FullScreen,

   }
\
\title{Summer 2024 Project (May 13 - June 13)}
\author{Supervisor: Prof 1}
\date{Local Supervisor: Prof 2}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

I would need to add in 2 images, specifically, institute logos at the bottom of the title page, with centering. Can someone please let me know how to do that?

Side-by-side with centering?  Anyway, you can use\includegraphics for the images, and either \raisebox or valign (adjustbox) to adjust the algnment.  You can use \makebox[0.5\textwidth]{...} to center the contents on half  a page.

BTW you don't need to resort to that titling, try
\title{Summer 2024 Project}
\author{Supervisor: Prof 1\Local Supervisor: Prof 2}
\date{May 13 - June 13}
